# Variable set to strictly equal variable returns true but function returns number less than variable it's equal to?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Observe the following function.

```js
function PermutationStep(num) { 
      var max = Number(String(num).split('').sort((a,b)=>b-a).join(''))
      console.log(max); // 9431
      for(var i = num; i < max; i++){
        let perm = Number(String(i).split('').sort((a,b) => b-a).join('')) === max;
        console.log(perm);
        if(i > num && perm) {  // I don't understand why this returns 9314 as opposed to the max since perm is set equal max.
          return i;
        }
      }
      return -1; 
    }

    console.log(PermutationStep(9143));
```

It's designed to take a number and then find the next permutation of that number. E.g. 9143 should return 9314.

I understand the code except for the one line; the if statement. If the max is === 9431 why does the function return 9314 as the permutation?

Answer (score 0):

Because this line:

```
let perm = Number(String(i).split('').sort((a,b) => b-a).join('')) === max;
```

...takes the digits of 9143 (`i`) and rearranges them into highest-first and converts back to a number. That number is 9431, which is `max`, so since `9431 === 9431` is `true`, `perm` is true. Then, in that `if`, `i > num` is satisfied (`9314 > 9143` is `true`) and `perm` is `true`, so the condition is satisfied.

Comment: Using that logic wouldn't 9144 also return true?

Comment: I must be missing something. The loop is going up one digit at time. What do you mean it doesn't get there?

Comment: @London804 - Sorry, the numbers got jumbled in my head. 9144 doesn't fit because `9411 === 9431` (`perm`) is `false`. Remember, the `if` uses `&&` ("and"). It requires that `i > num` **and** `perm` both be truthy. I suggest stepping through the code with the debugger built into your browser and/or IDE, so you can see exactly what's happening, what the values of the various variables are at any given moment, etc. You're starting at 9143, and so that's the first value you check. Since that value satisfies the `if` condition, you return on the first loop

Comment: Yea, but how does 9314 === 9431? I appreciate your help and i used the debugger, but I still don't quite understand.

Comment: @London804 - It doesn't. It's not comparing `i` to `max`, it's comparing the number formed by taking the digits and rearranging them into highest-first (9431); see the line I quoted in the answer above. So `i > num` is true (because 9314 is greater than 9143) and `perm` is true (because 9431 == 9431).

Answer (score -1):

The function determine the max and then will look for the next before the max.

The code

```
let perm = Number(String(i).split('').sort((a,b)=>b-a).join(''))===max;
```

is comparing **Number(String(i).split('').sort((a,b)=>b-a).join(''))** with **max**, and the **perm** var will be true or false.